# getting NSException while passing data from one viewController to another viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I am passing a data from one viewController to another viewController. But it is throwing `NSException`.

Here is my code.

**viewcontroller.m**

```
 NSString *empid1 = [dataDict objectForKey:@"EmployeeId"];
 NSLog(@"empid %@",empid1); //it prints 161.
 DashBoardViewController *dash = [[DashBoardViewController    alloc]initWithNibName:@"DashBoardViewController" bundle:nil];
 dash.empid = empid1;
```

**DashBoardViewController.h**

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * empid;
```

**DashBoardViewController.m**

```
NSString *strURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.1:8002/api/Case/GetCaseByEmployeeID/?empId=%@",_empid];
```

It throws data is `nil.NSException`.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is better if you post the full exception log.

Comment: you are pushing the VC, right???

Comment: are you using only xib or storyboard ?

Comment: Where is exact place you trying to use _empid ? Looks like you try to use _empid before it was set.

Comment: I am using storyboard...

Comment: I am not using the vc.  I am calling this line  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DashBoardViewController" sender:self];

Comment: Try my answer its work for you

Comment: @MuthuRaj check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plz use this you are using **storyboard**

pass your value like this

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DashBoardViewController" sender:[dataDict objectForKey:@"EmployeeId"]];
```

use this method when you use performSegueWithIdentifier

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DashBoardViewController"])
    {
        DashBoardViewController *dash= segue.destinationViewController;
      dash.empid =(NSString *)sender;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
YOURCONTROLLER *chatdetail=[[YOURCONTROLLER alloc] initWithNibName:@"YOURCONTROLLER_IDENTIFIER" bundle:nil];
chatdetail.strTitle = "YOUR VALUE"
[self.navigationController pushViewController:chatdetail animated:YES];
```

**Next Controller**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *strTitle;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
      NSLog(@"%@",self.strTitle);
}
```

Comment: I am using objective - c

Comment: @MuthuRaj try now

Comment: add navigation controller to your main viewcontroller and then try it

Answer (score 0):

### Reason

It is happening because the `DashboardViewController` Which you are instantiating and setting the property `empid` is different from the `DashboardViewController instance` on which segue is performed. You are instantiating it with the following code

```
 DashBoardViewController *dash = [[DashBoardViewController    alloc]initWithNibName:@"DashBoardViewController" bundle:nil];
 dash.empid = empid1;
```

But the `DashBoardViewController` which is being used by `iOS` is being created in `prepareForSegue` method and is different from `dash` created by you. For debugging purpose put some default value in `empid` property and then call `performSegueWithIdentifier`.It calls `prepareForSegue` method.**ViewController** on which segue will happen will be passed as `destinationViewController` as a parameter in this method whic will be of type `UIViewController`.Override this method.Downcast `destinationViewController` as `DashBoardViewController`.Log `empid` property.It will be having default value.Now log `empid` property of `dash`.It will be having correct value.So your instance is of no use here.

### Solution

Set the `empid` property in `prepareForSegue` as answered by **@balkaran singh** or if you want to use your `dash` variable then embed a `navigationController` and push `dash` on it without calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` as suggested by **@HImanshu Moradia** in previous answers.